# getline() / strsep() combination causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getline, strsep

I'm getting a segmentation fault when running the code below.

It should basically read a `.csv` file with over 3M lines and do other stuff afterwards (not relevant to the problem), but after 207746 iterations it returns a segmentation fault. If I remove the `p = strsep(&line,"|");` and just print the whole `line` it will print the >3M lines.

```
int ReadCSV (int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *line = NULL, *p;
    unsigned long count = 0;

    FILE *data;
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    if((data = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
        printf("the CSV file cannot be open");
        exit(0);
    }


    while (getline(&line, &len, data)>0) {

        p = strsep(&line,"|");  

        printf("Line number: %lu \t p: %s\n", count, p);
        count++;
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(data);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess it'd have to do with the memory allocation, but can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Does line #207746 have at least one delimiter in it?  strsep() behaves differently if it doesn't.

Comment: `strsep` modifies its first argument, so you're losing the start of the buffer `getline` first allocated for you. Don't do that, use a separate temporary if you must use `strsep`. And check `p` isn't NULL. And where is `len` declared? Is it zero before you call `getline`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of `getline` and `strsep` often causes confusion, because both functions change the pointer that you pass them by pointer as the initial argument. If you pass the pointer that has been through `strsep` to `getline` again, you run the risk of undefined behavior on the second iteration.

Consider an example: `getline` allocates 101 bytes to `line`, and reads a 100-character string into it. Note that `len` is now set to 101. You call `strsep`, which finds `'|'` in the middle of the string, so it points `line` to what used to be `line+50`. Now you call `getline` again. It sees another 100-character line, and concludes that it is OK to copy it into the buffer, because `len` is still 101. However, since `line` points to the middle of the buffer now, writing 100 characters becomes undefined behavior.

Make a copy of `line` before calling `strsep`:

```
while (getline(&line, &len, data)>0) {
    char *copy = line;
    p = strsep(&copy, "|");  
    printf("Line number: %lu \t p: %s\n", count, p);
    count++;
}
```

Now `line` that you pass to `getline` is preserved between loop iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the expression `getline(&line, &len, data)` and read the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> If *line is set to NULL and *len is set 0 before the call, then
>          getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>          should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

This should be the case on your first time round the loop (although we can't see where `len` is declared, let's just assume your real code does this correctly)

> Alternatively, before calling getline(), *line can contain a
>          pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *len bytes in size.  If the
>          buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it
>          with realloc(3), updating *line and *len as necessary.

OK, so if `line != NULL` it must point to a buffer allocated by `malloc` of size `len`. The buffer allocated by your first call to `getline` (as above) satisfies this.

Note it's not good enough for `line` to point *somewhere into* that buffer, it must be the beginning.

Now look at the expression `strsep(&line,"|")` and read the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) for *that*:

> ... This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a
>          null byte ('\0'), and *line is updated to point past the token

So, the first argument (`line`) is *changed* so that you can call `strsep` again with the same first argument, and get the *next* token. This means `line` is no longer a valid argument to `getline`, because it isn't the start of a `malloc`'d buffer (and the length `len` is also now wrong).

In practice, either

1. `getline` will try to read `len` bytes into the buffer you gave it, but since you advanced `line` by the length of the first token, it writes off the end of your allocated block. This might just damage the heap rather than dying immediately
2. `getline` will try to realloc the buffer you gave it, but since it isn't a valid allocated block, you get heap damage again.

While we're here, you also don't check `p` is non-NULL, but damaging `line` is the main problem.

Oh, and if you think the problem is allocation-related, try using `valgrind` - it generally finds the moment things first go wrong.